# Build dashboard

Tags: wso2

Is there a build dashboard somewhere for the different carbon/wso2 releases?

I just checked out the 4.0.3 tag of carbon ( https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.3)

and I was assuming tags are stable. But the build failed with the following error

```
The project org.wso2.carbon:SecVerifier:4.0.0
(/wso2/4.0.3/products/integration/security-verifier/pom.xml) has 1 error 
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find
org.wso2.carbon:integration:pom:4.0.0 in http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-incubating
repository was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until
the update interval of apache-incubating has elapsed or updates are forced and
'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 22, column 13 -> [Help 2]
```

Are these tags stable? I am using Maven 3.0.5 and Java 1.6

Comment: If you want to know how to build product sources, I answered it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490302/building-source-code-wso2-esb/15546317#15546317

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 build status dashboard can be found with [continuous build too, Bamboo](http://wso2.org/bamboo).

If you are trying to build something on a released branch, the easiest would be to build only that component, as for released versions, we have published maven repos with build artifacts.