# How to compile WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2-esb

I'm trying to build the source code of WSO2 ESB from the following URL https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.7/products/esb/4.6.0/

But when I'm compiling with Maven the project it throw me the following exception:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.  Software being installed: WSO2 Carbon - Axis2 Transport
>   HTTP Pass-through Feature 1.0.2
>   (org.wso2.carbon.transports.passthru.feature.group 1.0.2)  Missing
>   requirement: WSO2 Carbon - Axis2 Transport HTTP Pass-through Feature
>   1.0.2 (org.wso2.carbon.transports.passthru.feature.group 1.0.2) requires 'org.wso2.carbon.core.server.feature.group
>   [4.1.0.SNAPSHOT,4.2.0)' but it could not be found

What could be wrong? Is not the correct URL from the 4.6.0 source code?

Answer (score 3):

Reason is you dont have required dependencies to build WSO2 ESB. Below steps will helps you to build esb 4.6.0

1.Do checkout form" https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/orbit/tags/4.0.6/" and build it.

1. Get second checkout from "https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/tags/4.0.6/" and build it.
2. Finally get the checkout from  "https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.6/" and build below modules by order,parent, dependencies,service-stubs,components,features,samples/shopping-cart,samples/shopping-cart-global/2.0.0
3. Then go to the products/esb/4.6.0/ directory and build it.

Comment: Hi, i've tried what you told me but maven doesn't find the following artifacts in the source code checked out from  "https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/tags/4.0.6/":

- org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext
- org.wso2.carbon.user.api
- org.wso2.carbon.registry.xboot
- org.wso2.carbon.queuing
- org.wso2.carbon.core
- org.wso2.carbon.bridge
- org.wso2.carbon.http.bridge
- and more..

Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact org.wso2.carbon:integration:pom:4.0.0 in central (http://
repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

Comment: Did you build orbit module before that?

Comment: Yes we did it and the build was successfull.