# wso2 svn structure documentation

Tags: wso2

Is there any documentation available that describes the WSO2 svn structure?

It seems that the folder `https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/branches/` is deprecated.

**Question 1:** Should I only be working in the svn folder `https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/`?

In the `https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/` folder, I'm managing to piece bits together, for example the difference between Carbon **orbit**, **kernel** and **platform** (see [previous stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861292/what-is-wso2-orbit-kernel-and-platform)).

In the `https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/` folder, there are 3 sub-folders:

- 4.0.0
- 4.0.2AF
- 4.1.0

**Question 2**: 4.0.0 and 4.1.0 seem to be for the Carbon Platform, but what is 4.0.2AF  - Is this Application Factory?

**Question 3:** If I want to work on a specific version of Carbon say 4.0.3, it seems that I need to checkout the 4.0.0 branch.  What else do I need to do so that `mvn clean install` will build 4.0.3 for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: Should I only be working in the svn folder https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/?

WSO2 is currently doing active development in following svn directory.

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/

> **Question**: 4.0.0 and 4.1.0 seem to be for the Carbon Platform, but what is 4.0.2AF - Is this Application Factory?

The branches in https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/ are for the Carbon platform. The branch 4.0.2AF is for WSO2 App Factory (http://wso2.com/cloud/app-factory/)

> **Question**: If I want to work on a specific version of Carbon say 4.0.3, it seems that I need to checkout the 4.0.0 branch. What else do I need to do so that mvn clean install will build 4.0.3 for me?

You can build Carbon 4.0.3 from following:

https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.0.0/patch-releases/4.0.3/

You will be able to build products using the branch. That's why branch SVN URL is given in the links.

Each branch has a patch release for minor platform releases. For example: https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/patch-releases/

As mentioned in your answer, you can build from a tagged version also.

You can more details about product version and carbon version from the release matrix: http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/

You can also subscribe to WSO2 mailing [lists](http://wso2.com/mail) and get more information, if you have not subscribed already.

Comment: To build a patch release, do I simply need to change into the patch release directory (e.g. `./platform/branches/4.0.0/patch-releases/4.0.3/`) and perform `mvn clean install`?

Comment: Yes. You can open the pom.xml and see. All components, features, service stubs and products for relevant patch release will be built.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to **question 3** is build a checkout a tagged version (of course!!).  Thanks to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490302/building-source-code-wso2-esb) for pointing me in the right direction.

I was blindly following the [wiki documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Carbon403/Obtaining+the+Product) which tells you to checkout a branch.